# stored procedure returning value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

using this code :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[get](@i int)
AS
BEGIN
    declare @ADate datetime
    select @ADate = ADate 
    from table
    where i=@i
    and DateDiff(day ,getDate(), aDate  ) > 0
    and aDate is not null
    order by aDate asc
    return select @ADAte   
END
```

this returns 0 (or system 0 date time, which is not the desired result from the data base).

execute code

```
Declare @res datetime

exec @res = get 3

print @res
```

why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Stored Procedures in SQL Server can only RETURN *integers*.  If you need to return anything other than a single integer, then you should use one of these methods (some explained by the previous answers):

- Use a SELECT in your procedure
- Use an OUTPUT Parameter
- Use a User Defined Function instead

Comment: although you did not provide the code for the answer, you explained the problem as asked in the question, that is why this is the answer for the question.

Answer (score 7):

There isn't any need to declare a variable and assign a value to it. Just return the select statement.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[get](@i int)
AS
BEGIN

    select ADate 
    from table
    where i=@i
    and DateDiff(day ,getDate(), aDate  ) > 0
    and aDate is not null
    order by aDate asc

END
```

Although you should be aware that depending on your data this may return more than one value.

**EDIT**

If you want to you could do it this way:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[get](@i int, @date datetime output)
AS
BEGIN

    select @date = ADate 
    from table
    where i=@i
    and DateDiff(day ,getDate(), aDate  ) > 0
    and aDate is not null
    order by aDate asc

END
```

And then you can use it like so:

```
Declare @res datetime

exec get 3, @res

print @res
```

Comment: that does show in the managment studio the currect value, however it does not return the value after the "execute code"

Answer (score 1):

You should select the value:

```
select @OADate
```

Your value will be the first value in the first row on the first resultset.

Comment: the code return@ADate gives Msg 257, Level 16, State 3, Procedure get, Line 18
Implicit conversion from data type datetime to int is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Comment: @none - my bad, only ints can be used as return values from a SP. use Select.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [CREATE PROCEDURE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258259%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

you need to use the `OUTPUT` clause

```
**OUTPUT**

Indicates that the parameter is a return parameter. The value of this option can be returned to EXEC[UTE]. Use OUTPUT parameters to return information to the calling procedure.
```

Also, returning a single value seems like it is calling for a [USER DEFINED SCALAR FUNCTION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx), rather than a `STORED PROCEDURE`

Comment: No, you dont. That is unless you *want* it to be an output variable in oppose to a return value.

Comment: i gave up, i just turned it into output since i could not use the technology of return in sql stored procedure. failed technology.(could it be that only int can be return?, what does it mean and wtf?)

Comment: @none, have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx. it states *Exits unconditionally from a query or procedure. RETURN is immediate and complete and can be used at any point to exit from a procedure, batch, or statement block. Statements that follow RETURN are not executed.*